# Clickable phone number in TextView

Tags: android

I have a String that might contain a phone number and I want that phone number to be clickable so the dial pad comes up when clicked. I achieved this with

```
        textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Problem is on Android 2.3 the following phone number: `555/1233` only the numbers `555` will be part of the link. 
I know I could just filter the slash out of my phone number String but I wonder if theres a method to keep the slash in and still have the whole number linkified.

I found [the class sPhoneNumberTransformFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#sPhoneNumberTransformFilter) but I don't know how to use it here.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way

```
Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new TransformFilter() {
    @Override
    public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
        return url.replaceAll("/", "");
    }
};

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9/]+");
Linkify.addLinks(tv, pattern, "tel:", null, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView myCustomLink3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{3}");
myCustomLink3.setText("123/999");
Linkify.addLinks(myCustomLink3, pattern3, "tel:", null, filter);

}

Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new TransformFilter() {
    @Override
    public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
        return url;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does the same as what I did, it linkifies 555 but not 1234.

Comment: I Edited my answer, haven't tested it on 2.3 but I don't see why it should not work